# Fancybox not working in glob foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach, fancybox, glob

I got a problem with my fancy box, I'm using 2 foreach loops to loop through my folders and loop the images, for some reason whem using the loops my fancy box isn't working but without using the loops it does work..

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <?php
        $folderGlob = glob("gallery/2015/*/");
        foreach ($folderGlob as $folder){
        ?>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo $folder; ?></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <?php
                $fileGlob = glob($folder . "*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
                foreach ($fileGlob as $file):
                  $basename = basename($file, ".jpg");
                  $date = current(explode("_", $basename));
                ?>
                  <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
                    <a class="fancybox-effects-d" href="<?php echo $file; ?>" title="<?php echo $date . ' januari 2015'; ?>">
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $file; ?>" alt=""/>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                <?php
                endforeach;
              ?>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">

            </div>
          </div>
        <?php
      }
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I dont know what i did wrong ..

Comment: What is the HTML output of your `foreach()`s?

Comment: everything works, just the fancy box pop up effect stopped working, want me to upload it to my website ?

Comment: Nop, I'd like you to post the code of the generated HTML by your PHP code.

Comment: view-source:http://kiggdesigns.nl/dvp2/ or https://jsfiddle.net/h759k8op/

Comment: Looks like a `CSS` problem to me.

Comment: why does it work if i just use plain html then ?